# Capture STDIN / STDERR / STDOUT of a process AFTER it's been started, using command line?

Tags: linux, bash, output, putty

Thanks! My usercase: I started a lengthy interactive 'configure' process (say under 'screen'), and then realised I need to always answer 'no' until I see a particular keyword. Seems a waste of time to do this by hand (not to say that I can easily miss the keyword..)

Thus it seems I want to pipe (a copy of) STDERR / STDOUT to a filter, 
and also be able to inject into the STDIN of a (console) process, 
AFTER it's been started, using command line? Is there a ready-made solution?

The following tools seem help. To capture output, use

```
strace -ewrite -p $PID
```

It's not that clean (shows lines like: write(#,) ), but works!
But does it say handle UTF8 correctly?

To redirect the output, do something like

```
printf '..input..' >/dev/pts/33
```

But it is not clear how to find the right device..

Comment: You should add your resolution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved in Linux (apparently Linux-specific):

```
reptyr -s PID
```

attaches a process to another terminal and/or exposes its input and output as pipes.

Answer (score 3):

This is possible but it's not pretty.  The process is as follows:

1. use `gdb` to attach to the already running process
2. run `p close(<fd>)` where `<fd>` is the file descriptor you want to change
3. run `p creat("<path to file">, <perms>)` to send the output of the closed `fd` somewhere else

See [This Link](http://etbe.coker.com.au/2008/02/27/redirecting-output-from-a-running-process/) for more detailed information

Comment: Rather than `close()` on the fd, you may want to create the new fd first (`creat()`, `open()`, etc) then use `dup2()` to replace the fd you want to capture, and then `close()` the new fd. The reason is that `open()` etc will always give the lowest available fd, so if you close a fd and open right after, there's no guarantee you'll get back the same fd. Maybe not as important for stdin/stdout/stderr because they're fd 0,1,2, but worth mentioning for the general case.

Comment: little program  reptyr -s PID does just that

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to do that??

It is not possible in a portable Posix-ly way! Maybe `open`-ing the `/proc/1234/fd/0` and `/proc/1234/fd/1` and `/proc/1234/fd/3` pseudo-files (for process 1234) could be an ugly possiblity! And even that might not work in some cases (e.g. for pipes).

In particular, I believe that the semantics of `SIGPIPE` sent to the process if nobody is reading a pipe would be broken...

And I don't believe that you would be able to keep the pseudo-tty quality of e.g. *stdout* .

So basically, you'll better find a different way to achieve your overall goals, which you did not explain explicitly.

If your use-case is some weird `configure` script, you could restart it and feed it with some script of your own (in shell, python, perl, etc...). Don't lose time to try to catch an existing `configure` process, just restart it appropriately.

Look also at the `screen`  command (and how it is implemented!)

Comment: Thanks! My usercase: I started a lengthy interactive 'configure' process (say under 'screen'), and then realised I need to answer 'no'

Comment: Thanks! My usercase: I started a lengthy interactive 'configure' process (say under 'screen'), and then realised I need to always answer 'no' until I see a particular keyword. Seems a waste of time to do this by hand (not to say that I can easily miss the keyword..)

Comment: Thanks again! My point is that it would be very handy sometimes to be able to do this, with any process; 'configure' is only an example..'screen' can do it something like that, but not quite: you can filter ( :exec !..| less ) either input or output, but not both. Seems I have to write my own script then..

Comment: If you find that handy (but I don't) consider contributing to the linux kernel some new system calls to implement it. Then modify shells for that. Participate to the free software movement!

Comment: Basile, my question is solved: reptyr -s PID does what i want, and seems reliable enough.